# How to prove that a filter intersects all the dense sets?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Let $(\mathbb{P},\le)$ be a partial order and consider the following definitions

- $G\subseteq\mathbb{P}$ is filter iff $\forall p,q\in G\exists r\in G(r\le p\wedge r\le q)$ and $\forall p\in\mathbb{P}\forall q\in G(q\le p\rightarrow p\in G)$.
- $D\subseteq \mathbb{P}$ is dense iff $\forall p\in\mathbb{P}\exists q\in D(q\leq p)$.
- $A\subseteq\mathbb{P}$ is antichain iff $\forall p,q\in A\neg\exists r\in \mathbb{P}(r\leq p\wedge r\leq q)$.

I want to proof the following two statement are equivalent

1. $G\cap D\neq\emptyset$ for all dense $D\subseteq\mathbb{P}$.
2. $G\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for all maximal antichain $A\subseteq\mathbb{P}$.

**Proof:** ($\rightarrow$). Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{P}$ be an antichain. Let $A'=\cup_{p\in A}p\downarrow$ where $p\downarrow:=\{q\in\mathbb{P}:q\leq p\}$. It is easy to see that $A'$ is dense (by maximality of $A$) so $G\cap A'\neq\emptyset$. Then exists $p\in A$ such that $G\cap p\downarrow\neq\emptyset$. As $G$ is filter, we can get $p\in G$, so $G\cap A\neq\emptyset$.

I have troubles with the proof of the another direction. Can someone give me a hint?

(please, don't give me the answer.)

Comment: Given a dense set $D,$ a maximal antichain in $D$ will be a maximal antichain in $\mathbb P.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks, your suggest was helpful to complete my proof.

Comment: By your definition of dense, {0} is dense subset of [0,1].

Comment: By your definition of antichain {0}, is the only anti chain of [0,1], contrary to the accepted definition of antichain.

Comment: It appears you are  using the term antichain to mean a set of minimal elements.

Comment: For 2 implies 1, what happens if P has no antichains?

Comment: In your definition of antichain, you need to use r < p & r < q for there to be any antichains.  Either that or require p and q to be distinct.

Comment: @WilliamElliot In the context that I'm working (the context of forcing) the well-ordered set are not interesting (as you point it). This definitions are not trivial in the case that $\mathbb{P}$ is a  decreasing tree, for instance.

Comment: @WilliamElliot If $\mathbb{P}$ has not antichains, then the proof follows for vacuity

Comment: @WilliamElliot You have reason, $p,q$ must be differents in the definition of antichain, so each set with an unique element can be an antichain.

Comment: By your definition of antichain {0} is not an antichain of [0,1] because 0 <= 0.  If you use < in the defintion, then {0} would be an antichain,  Even with that change, {1} is not an antichain because 0 < 1. @Gödel

Comment: The misnomered defintion of dense is the definition of cointial, the order reverse dual of cofinal.  It is the only use of coinitial I've ever seen. @Gödel

Comment: @WilliamElliot Aside from the fact that $p\ne q$ should have been stipulated in the definition of antichain, their definitions are completely standard in this context. See any reference on forcing with posets, e.g. Kunen’s set theory book.

Comment: @WilliamElliot. Any $1$-member subset of $\Bbb P,$ and also the empty set, is an anti-chain.